# Migrate Changes from a Staging Site to Production

Tags: migration, staging, production

Is there a tool that allows me to "record" changes to a staging site and later replay them on production?

It is a common usecase for me to set up a staging site (Duplicator is great for that) and implement design changes (including menus, etc.) there for the customer to review. Those changes at some point need to go to production. Works well with files (plugins, themes), but not with the database.

The production system is being used all the time and authors will add content while I'm working on the staging site. Hence I can't simply copy over the whole posts table.

Instead I'd need a solution that records any SQL statement made to selected tables and replays them on production later on. Is there such a solution out there?

Comment: The short answer here is no.  Delicious Brains was working on a solution for this called [Mergebot](https://deliciousbrains.com/wp-migrate-db-pro/doc/mergebot/) and gave up after dumping time and money into it for 2 years.

Answer (score 0):

Note: This is more a comment than an answer, but I wanted to format it nicely.

I don't know about recording, but I imagine something like the following in SQL could work.

```
INSERT INTO         DB1.Tbl1 ( id, x, y )
  SELECT            DB2.Tbl1.id, DB2.Tbl1.x, DB2.Tbl1.y
    FROM            DB2.Tbl1  
  ON DUPLICATE KEY  
    UPDATE          x=x, y=y;
```

Beware, this is completely untested. You have to test it and read up on the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert.html) yourself.

Comment: That doesn't seem to even remotely address the question.

Comment: It's a possibility to migrate changes from one database to another. @Patrick